Providing support after project is completed
I worked on a complex project for a client that started in January this year, and was finished in August. It involved a very challenging API sync and bidirectional communication, but I handled it well I think.
Three months ago, the script stopped working, but it wasn’t due to my work. The issue was caused by the API limiting data, which led to the problem. I had to reset the script, and I went above and beyond to assist the client, even on Sundays and National Holidays. Each time I did that, the script continued to work perfectly.
I can provide bug fixes and optimize the script further now, but knowing the issue wasn’t my fault, should I expect compensation? Is it standard practice to offer free support after a project is completed? Or perhaps I should provide lifetime support for free ?
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Assuming you had a written contract, ideally the conditions regarding post-delivery support should have been specified there.
If this is not the case and there has been no other mention of any future support, it would be reasonable to assume that support is not covered by the original contract.
Before doing any more (potentially) free work, now would be a good time to draw up a new contract stating the requirements and expectations of both parties regarding future client needs. In addition to support, the new contract could also involve general updates you provide and custom requirements the client would want.
Usual solutions are either being paid by the hour or the client paying for a retainer that they may use (or not).
The client may be relunctant to sign a contract if you are currently working for free, in which case you might need to risk souring the client relationship. Crafting a contract that has the primary goal of being mutually beneficial and future-proof is the best way to un-sour the relationship.

Thank you so much ! What do you mean by this "the client paying for a retainer that they may use (or not)" ?

A 'retainer' is an agreement that the client pays (sometimes in advance) for having a guaranteed availability from you in a certain period, like three months. This works better when there is a somewhat steady flow of work over time. See for example: https://www.forecast.app/blog/retainer-agreements-complete-guide

Thank you very much
